# Selecting a player and the position using winium

Tags: java, winium

I have a scenario to select 8 players and at the same time click their positions.Scenario like this double click a player first, after selection there is window for selecting player position..

here my code will take all players and printing their names... I am doing that first select the table and select the row and then select column to take the each players in the list...

```
 try {
             Thread.sleep(4000);     
             WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@AutomationId='lsvAwayTeamHitters1']"));
             List<WebElement> row= table.findElements(By.xpath("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'item')]"));
             int row_size = row.size();
             System.out.println(row_size);

             int col_size = 0;
             for(int i=0;i<row.size();i++)
             {

             List<WebElement> col = row.get(i).findElements(By.xpath("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'text')]"));
                 col_size = col.size();
                 System.out.println(col_size);

                 for(int j=0;j<col.size();j++)
                 {
                     Thread.sleep(40000);
                     String celtext = col.get(j).getAttribute("Name");
                     System.out.println(celtext);
                     Thread.sleep(4000);

                 }
                 Thread.sleep(20000);
             }
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
         }

      }
}
```

But now I want to select 8 players in the list, initially i do double click a plyer and then select their position for a click....

this is the player selection.. code..

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
 act.doubleClick(elem.get(j)).build().perform();
```

this is for select their position...

```
List<WebElement> rowCount= driver.findElementsById("PlayerPositions");
            rowCount.get(i).click();
```

Comment: `act.doubleClick(elem.get(j).findElement((By.name(Integer.toString(j))))).build().perform();` doesn't seem correct

Comment: Are you using some extenstion of a WebDriver? What is findElementsByName method doing and why are you casting it to List<WebElement> ? You get index outofBount exception because your list is empty, I mean no elements were found in the very first line.

Comment: @MivaScott  please check my question...I'm stuck..please help me...https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/33791/unable-to-double-click-the-list-of-players-from-the-table-in-the-exact-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
List<WebElement> elem= driver.findElements(By.id("lsvAwayTeamHitters1"));
```

You're creating a List<> of 1, which is why you're getting the error: **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out-of-bounds for length 1**

It says right there that the it has a length of 1 (one record) and you're trying to access index 2, which is out of bounds.

You are trying to find elements `By.id()`. By design, id's are (or at least should be) unique to a page. So if your List<> is searching for an id, it will only find the one element so you will only ever have `elem.get(0)`.

Once you find a better way to identify all the elements you want to use, then you can loop through the List<> and do what you need to do.

```
int elemSize = elem.size();
for (int i = 0; i < elemSize; i++) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: @Anthony, you are iterating through the list with `i`, but the statement where you access the elements you use `j` - `act.doubleClick(elem.get(j)).build().perform();` Also, you're still using ID to mind a list of elements. I suggest rethinking how you're approaching this.

Comment: At this point, there is nothing more that can be done without more details; such as the HTML you're trying to read. This solved the original question; an error with the loop. I suggest selecting an answer and opening up a new question with the new problem with HTML and your code included.

Comment: can you check my question that i have edited

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing as `driver.findElementsByName("0-9")`, the proper way to write is `driver.findElements(By.id("a"));`(Just an example).

If you are using specific methods the please don't mind. 
As **Alexy.R** mentioned the error is because the **List** contains **0** elements are you are accessing from **2**. So it is better if you move

```
List<WebElement> elem= (List<WebElement>) driver.findElementsByName("0-9");
```

this code into the **try-catch** and check. Is there any specific reason for starting the loop from **2**?. Before that add a `Thread.sleep(4000);` and check whether it is working. Since you said after clicking it opens a pop-up, it may take few seconds to move into the new window. 
Also check whether the elements in the pop-up is verified correctly.

Check the below code,

```
       try {
          Thread.sleep(4000)
          List<WebElement> elem= driver.findElements(By.id("lsvAwayTeamHitters1"));

        for(int i=2;i<elem.size();i++) 
        {
            for(int j=2;j<=i;j++)
            {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            Actions act = new Actions(driver);
            act.doubleClick(elem.get(j)).build().perform();

            }
            Thread.sleep(20000);
             List<WebElement> rowCount= driver.findElementsById("PlayerPositions");
            rowCount.get(i).click();
        }          }
       catch (Exception e)
        {
           System.out.println(e);

        }
       }
```

Please run the code and if error exists please paste the error in the question. So that we can check from which line the error is occuring.
**Note** :- If you can please paste the html for the same.

Comment: @Anthony Can you pls add the html.

Comment: Did you mean web application?

Comment: @Anthony Without the relevant html I will not be able to check the issue.

Comment: can you check that i have edited